# Angular performance tracking

Tags: angular, performancecounter, page-load-time

What is best and recommended way to track an Angular application performance? I can use many other available techniques/api's like performance.now to track and  google analytics/application insight to send custom performance counters.

But my question is do we have something built-in inside Angular for this purpose or a recommend third party module/library that helps to track angular application performance?

Comment: I'm suggesting [Augury](https://augury.angular.io/pages/guides/), an Angular inspection Tool, pretty useful during development.

Comment: I know about Augury I am more interested in a tool by which we can also track performance data from production not only during development.

Comment: Not perf. related, but maybe [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/) ?

Comment: SonalQube seems interesting

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for something like **Perfume.js**: https://zizzamia.github.io/perfume/#/angular/

It tracks things like First Contentful Paint and First Input Delay for user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend using the package **perf-marks**. It's an:

> isomorphic, simple, and lightweight solution for User Timing API in Javascript - **only 208B** used in projects such as Jira, Confluence, and Bitbucket. Tree-shaking and entry points built-in.

Also, you can use it on your browser or NodeJS sides.

https://github.com/willmendesneto/perf-marks